# C# Dedupe a List with a List and Combine the List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What is the best way to dedupe a list with a list? rough class example:

```
Class CustomType{
 string prop1
 string prop2
 string prop3
 int quantity
 List<AnotherCustomType> serials
}
```

So I have a list of CustomType objects.
I started trying to do a group by but got hung up on the list. I need to combine items in the list with the same prop1 and prop2 and combine their lists (serials) and combined quantities.

I started down this road...

```
 List<CustomType> c = (from x in items
                                  group x by new {
                                      x.prop1, x.prop2
                                  } into y
                                  select new CustomType {
                                  quantity = y.Sum(z => z.quantity),
                                  prop1 = y.prop1,
                                  prop2=y.prop2,
                                  prop3 = y.prop3,
                                  serials= ????? how do I combine the lists
}
```

Am I way off?

Comment: How do you want them combined?  Do you want one added to the other?  Do you want duplicate values removed?  Do you want them sorted?  Do you have a sample to illustrate what you want?

Comment: `y.prop3` is not defined. Your `CustomType` lacks of `;`, it's `class` not `Class`, your indentation is poor, you didn't tell what you want.....

Comment: create a hash function and override equalsto and then use a HashSet

Comment: Without knowing exactly what AnotherCustomType looks like... My quick suggestion is to take a look at SelectMany to flatten the "serials" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0 and then use a Distinct to remove the duplicates https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the method `SelectMany` to flatten `serials`:

```cs
List<CustomType> c = (from x in items
                            group x by new
                            {
                                x.prop1,
                                x.prop2
                            } into y
                            select new CustomType
                            {
                                quantity = y.Sum(z => z.quantity),
                                prop1 = y.Key.prop1,
                                prop2 = y.Key.prop2,
                                prop3 = y.First().prop3,
                                serials = y.SelectMany(item => item.serials).ToList()
                            }).ToList();
```